# How to use Named Filters in the Adaptable Blotter

Tags: datagrid, ag-grid

We want to use Named Filters in the Adaptable Blotter which look powerful.  We can see where you create the Filter in the Predefined Config but cannot work out where you put the actual implementation code.

We have tried using Predefined Config for the actual logic for the Filter but there doesnt seem to be anywhere suitable.

Answer (score 0):

as dev on Adaptable Blotter team I can answer that:)

You need to put the actual function in the advanced options section of your Blotter Options.  You cannot put it in Config as that is JSON and it wont accept code.  So you put it in advanced options and the Blotter will then find it at run time and evaluate it as required each time.

See https://api.adaptableblotter.com/interfaces/_blotteroptions_adaptableblotteroptions_.adaptableblotteroptions.html#advancedoptions